# how to make preg_match accept - or ( )

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

When insert phone number users tend to type in various way like `083-XXXXXXX` or `(083)XXXXXXX` or `XXXXXXX`. I mean the extension and the phone or sometimes just the phone. How to make `preg_match()` accept the `-XXX` or `(XXX)` then return the real phone? For example `(083) 1234567` will be `1234567`.

I used this method:

```
preg_match("/^[-0-9]{10,20}$/",$value); 
preg_replace("/(083-)/","",$value);
```

But it seems only accept the `083-`. I want it can accept either `-083` or `(083)`

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: i used this method
preg_match("/^[-0-9]{10,20}$/",$value);
preg_replace("/(083-)/","",$value);
but it seems only accept the 083-. I want it can accpet either -083 or (083)

Comment: Just process the string to remove non-numeric characters then read the rest (knock off the 083 if you want).

Comment: @AnNguyễnLêThái looks now your question makes more sense :)

Comment: why not do `$value = preg_replace("/\D+/", "", $value);` to remove all non-digits first?

Comment: why even taking first 3 digit instead you can take only allowed number and get those first three digit automatically on the basis of country

Answer (score 1):

Here you are :
`$value = preg_replace('/^((?:\(\d+\)|\d+)[- ]?)?(\d+)$/', '$2', $value);`

Answer (score 0):

Having this pattern:

```
/(?:(?:\(\d+\))|(?:\d+-))(\d+)/g
```

will return the phone number without country/province code. See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/hC1aD3).

Answer (score 0):

This pattern will work:

```
~^(\(\d+\)|\d+\-)?\d{10,20}$~
```

This is the test script:

```
<?php

$pattern = ''; // the regexp
$input = ''; // the phone number

$valid = preg_match($pattern, $input) ? 'valid' : 'INVALID';

echo 'The number is ' . $valid; // it prints out valid if phone number accepts prints out INVALID if phone number rejects
?>
```

My pattern:

```
~^(\(\d+\)|\d+\-)?\d{10,20}$~
```

Mmm... Let's test it!

```
$pattern = '~^(\(\d+\)|\d+\-)?\d{10,20}$~';
$input = '(083)0123456789';
```

output: `The number is valid`

Next number...

```
$input = '0123456789';
```

output: `The number is valid`

Next:

```
$input = '083-0123456789';
```

output: `The number is valid`

Let's test an **INVALID** number to make sure it works correctly

```
$input = '083+0123456789';
```

output: `The number is INVALID`

**Next Step: Removing The Prefix**

Code:

```
echo preg_replace('~(\(\d+\)|\d+\-)~', '', $input);
// input:(083)0123456789 , output: 0123456789
// input: 0123456789, output: 0123456789 
// input: 083-0123456789, output: 0123456789
```

Finished!

Comment: it is really helpful but can you explain what is the meaning of the "~" character. Iam little bit confused about it

Comment: "~" doesn't have a special meaning. It's only a delimiter just like "/". P.S: You can vote up instead of saying it's helpful! :)